# Compute unweighted bag-of-words based TCM using text2vec in R?

Tags: r, nlp, n-gram, text2vec

I am trying to compute a term-term co-occurrence matrix (or TCM) from a corpus using the `text2vec` package in `R` (since it has a nice parallel backend). I followed [this tutorial](http://text2vec.org/glove.html), but while inspecting some toy examples, I noticed the `create_tcm` function does some sort of scaling or weighting on the term-term co-occurrence values. I know it uses skip-grams internally, but the documentation does not mention how it scales them - clearly, more distant terms/unigrams are weighted lower.

Here is an example:

```
tcmtest = function(sentences){
  tokens <- space_tokenizer(sentences)
  it = itoken(tokens, progressbar = FALSE)
  vocab <- create_vocabulary(it, ngram = c(ngram_min = 1L, ngram_max = 1L))
  vectorizer <- vocab_vectorizer(vocab,  grow_dtm = FALSE, skip_grams_window = 5L)
  return(create_tcm(it, vectorizer))
}

> tcmtest(c("a b", "a b c"))
3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
  b c   a
b . 1 2.0
c . . 0.5
a . . .  
> tcmtest(c("a b", "c a b"))
3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
  b   c a
b . 0.5 2
c . .   1
a . .   .
> tcmtest(c("a b", "c a a a b"))
3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
  b    c        a
b . 0.25 2.833333
c . .    1.833333
a . .    .
```

**Question**: is there any way to disable this behaviour, so that every term/unigram in the skip-gram window is treated equally? I.e., if a term occurs inside the context window of another term twice in a corpus, it should say "2" in the TCM matrix.

Bonus question: how does the default scaling thing work anyway? If you add more "a"s to the last example, then the b-c value seems to linearly decrease, while the b-a value actually increases - although more occurrences or "a" appear further away from "b".

Comment: Bonus question: In the last example, "b" is the 4th letter from c. That's 1/4. For "a" and "c", you have "a" at 1, 2, and 3 letters from c. That's 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 = 1.833333. For "b" and "a", you have 2 occasions where "a" is right next to "b", then two more instances of "a" where it is at a distance of 2 and 3 from "b", respectively.  That's 2 + 1/2 + 1/3.  Since you have `skip_grams_window = 5`, `c("a b", "c a a a a a a b")` and `c("a b", "c a a a a a b")` will produce the same result from `tcmtest`.

Comment: @Jota cool, that makes sense. Now how do I bypass this scaling thing?

Comment: @user3554004 in fact you are not using any parallel backend in your example. See how we create `jobs` in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/vignettes/files-multicore.html#multicore_machines). Also I want to add, that using parallel backend to `tcm` make sense only for very large corpuses.

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov thanks for the comment; I'm just starting out, and this is very helpful. If you don't mind me asking, where is the range where a corpus (in tokens) would be considered large enough to justify parallelizing the tcm job? (from what I understand, glove fitting uses low-level parallelism by default?)

Comment: @user3554004 GloVe fitting done with RcppParallel so there is no overhead (both ram and cpu). `tcm`creation is different - we compute it for each chunk and then sum them, [see here](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/blob/93f656bc082c2f989da067b55dc1037b6a97d81d/R/tcm.R#L119-L142). However in this case we face overhead in memory consumption...  As long as we have enough RAM we can try to grow it in parallel. But from my experience `tcm` building usually is not a bottleneck - we build it once and the reuse many times. Creation of `tcm` in 1 thread on english wikipedia takes ~ 2 hours.

Comment: @user3554004 now (text2vec >= 0.5) you can specify weighting vector directly in `create_tcm` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2017-02-01**
[Pushed update to github](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/commit/5a6683236722697749a727ac204b1ef14c4d7261) - now you can specify weighting vector directly in `create_tcm`.

Weighting function is defined [here](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/blob/08d4362027a5a3d3701d65858cbc4b78410acf36/src/Corpus.h#L72-L74).
If you need equal weight for each term within window, you need to adjust weighting function to always return `1` (just clone repo, change function definition and build package from source with `devtools` or `R CMD build`):

```
inline float weighting_fun(uint32_t offset) {
  return 1.0;
}
```

However several people already asked for this feature and I will probably include such option in next release.